# Adjust column position after split

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that is positioned in the middle of a dataframe. I need to split it into multiple columns, and replace it with the new columns. I'm able to do it with the following code:

`df = df.join(df[col_to_split].str.split(', ', expand=True).add_prefix(col_to_split + '_'))`

However, the new columns are placed at the end of the dataframe, rather than replacing the original column. I need a way to place the new columns at the same position of original columns.

Note that I don't want to manually order ALL columns (i.e. `df = df[[c1, c2, c3 ... cn]]`) because of many reasons, i.e.it's not known how many new columns are going to be generated, and dataframe contains hundreds of columns.

Sample data:

```
c1  c2  c3  col_to_split    c4  c5  ... cn
1   a   b   1,5,3           1   1   ... 1
2   a   c   5,10            3   3   ... 4
3   z   c   3               2   3   ... 4
```

Desired output:

```
c1  c2  c3  col_to_split_0  col_to_split_1  col_to_split_2  c4  c5  ... cn
1   a   b   1               5               3               1   1   ... 1
2   a   c   5               10                              3   3   ... 4
3   z   c   3                                               2   3   ... 4
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use your solution with dynamic insert `df1.columns` to original columns with `cols[pos:pos]` trick, position of original column is count by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
col_to_split = 'col_to_split'

cols = df.columns.tolist()
pos = df.columns.get_loc(col_to_split)
df1 = df[col_to_split].str.split(',', expand=True).fillna("").add_prefix(col_to_split + '_')
cols[pos:pos] = df1.columns.tolist()
cols.remove(col_to_split)
print (cols)
['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'col_to_split_0', 'col_to_split_1', 'col_to_split_2',
 'c4', 'c5', 'cn']

df = df.join(df1).reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
   c1 c2 c3 col_to_split_0 col_to_split_1 col_to_split_2  c4  c5  cn
0   1  a  b              1              5              3   1   1   1
1   2  a  c              5             10                  3   3   4
2   3  z  c              3                                 2   3   4
```

Similar solution for join columsn names in lists:

```
col_to_split = 'col_to_split' 

pos = df.columns.get_loc(col_to_split)
df1 = df[col_to_split].str.split(",", expand=True).fillna("").add_prefix(col_to_split + '_')

cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[:pos] + df1.columns.tolist() + cols[pos+1:]
print(cols)
['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'col_to_split_0', 'col_to_split_1', 'col_to_split_2',
'c4', 'c5', 'cn']

df = df.join(df1).reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
   c1 c2 c3 col_to_split_0 col_to_split_1 col_to_split_2  c4  c5  cn
0   1  a  b              1              5              3   1   1   1
1   2  a  c              5             10                  3   3   4
2   3  z  c              3                                 2   3   4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap this operation to a function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""c1  c2  c3  col_to_split    c4  c5  cn
1   a   b   1,5,3           1   1   1
2   a   c   5,10            3   3   4
3   z   c   3               2   3   4"""), sep="\s+")


def split_by_col(df, colname):
    pos = df.columns.tolist().index(colname)
    df_tmp = df[colname].str.split(",", expand=True).fillna("")
    df_tmp.columns=["col_to_split_" + str(i) for i in range(len(df_tmp.columns))]
    return pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:pos], df_tmp, df.iloc[:,pos+1:]], axis=1)
```

With example:

```
>>> split_by_col(df, "col_to_split")
   c1 c2 c3 col_to_split_0 col_to_split_1 col_to_split_2  c4  c5  cn
0   1  a  b              1              5              3   1   1   1
1   2  a  c              5             10                  3   3   4
2   3  z  c              3                                 2   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.join(df[col_to_split].str.split(', ', expand=True).add_prefix(col_to_split + '_'))
df = df[["c1", "c2", "c3"  "col_to_split_0"  "col_to_split_1"  "col_to_split_2"  "c4"  "c5"  ... "cn"]]
```